# Redirect to some other page then animate to reach a certain scrollTop

Tags: jquery

Want to do exactly what going to internal links of another page does! But through jquery.
Can't use regular external jumps as using parallax scrolling which doesn't go well with jumps like that.

for internal links, I used something like this-

```
    $(function() {
    $("#clickNews").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 2400}, 1500);
    }); 
});
```

But how to perform redirecting followed by animate() ?

I want to click an anchor on a page.. to got to another page's certain scrollTop

IS THERE A WAY LIKE THIS-->>

```
$("#clickCatalog").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = '/ABC/';
    window.load(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1500);  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh Boy! It was a stupid question. The problem was real, but the way to ask was stupid. I don't even remember what I did back then. But now I will probably just redirect it like this :

```
window.loation.href = '/link/?scroll=top'
```

and on the target page, I will just check for the query string like this and apply scrolltop animation :

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
if(urlParams.get('scroll') == 'top'){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
}
```

Thanks for all of your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the documentation of animate function
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

You can either pass a function that will redirect as fourth parameter or pass options object with 'complete' key with function as value

something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#clickNews").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 2400}, {
           duration: 1500,
           complete: function() {
              window.location = '{url}';
           }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: You got the order wrong.  You did animate followed by redirect.  He wanted redirect then animate

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing you can do is to load through ajax the page you want, loaded into an element.

Something along the lines of:

```
$('a.internal').click(function(event){ //Put class="internal" to load with ajax...
   event.stopPropagation();
   event.preventDefault();
   var newPage = $('<div class="page"></div>');
   var oldPage = $('.page');
   newPage.css('opacity',0);
   oldPage.animate({opacity:0, top: -5000 }, {
     complete: function(){
        newPage.animate({opacity:1});
     }
   }
   newPage.load('http://localhost/myNewPage.html body >');
   $('body').append(newPage).animate({'scrollTop':0});

});
```

Mind you it is untested but it should work.

**EDIT: Fixed a few typos**

Comment: sorry but didn't work.. actually it has some problem with these lines.. I tried to fix but couldn't get it anyway!

"oldPage.animate({opacity:0, top: -5000px}}, {
     complete: function(){
        newPage.animate({opacity:1}
     }
   }"

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `localStorage` to do this task. I tried once and it works for me. I use this in my navigation tab, that's why I'm passing the element `id` to the `localStorage`.

```
$('#block li').click(function (){
    //get the clicked element's id. eg:- id='1'
    var menu_selector = $(this).attr('id');
    //store the value into localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('selector', menu_selector);
    //do the redirection
    window.location.replace("/about");
});

//if localStorage is not empty  
if(localStorage.getItem('selector') != 'undefined' && localStorage.getItem('selector') != null) {
    // get the stored values
    var selector = localStorage.getItem('selector');

    //I'm asuming, my destination is <div id="destination-1"></div>
    var destination = $('#destination-'+selector);

    //now do the scrollTop
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: destination.offset().top - 50
    }, 700);

    //distroy the local storage
    window.localStorage.clear();
});
```

Also note this will not works for very old browsers.