# Redirect to other html page and scrollTop: to a certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

It's been already asked, but the two given answers don't work for me. 
[Redirect to some other page then animate to reach a certain scrollTop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813897/redirect-to-some-other-page-then-animate-to-reach-a-certain-scrolltop)
My html is something like:

html1:

```
<!doctype html>
<html clalang="en">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
       <a href="index.html" id="boxes">boxes</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

html2:

```
<!doctype html>
<html clalang="en">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="goto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So I need when you click on  in html1 to go to  in html2

Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what a url hash is for:

```
<a href="index.html#goto" id="boxes">boxes</a>
```

Browser will automatically scroll to the matching id