# JQuery scroll to div id even it's not on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have my button scrolling to div I want even it's not on the same page.
This is what I have:

```
$("#smooth").click(function() {       //#smooth is the id of my button
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop:$("#map").offset().top   //#map - where is scrolling to.
            }, 900);
```

});

This is working but only when I'm on the page where #map is. I want to working when I'm pressing #smooth from all the pages. #smooth is located on homepage. What should I do?

Comment: Check if any of these answers help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813897/redirect-to-some-other-page-then-animate-to-reach-a-certain-scrolltop

Comment: post your html plz

Comment: By definition, isn't 'scroll' on the same page?  Perhaps you want the verb 'redirect'?

Comment: Yes. That's what I wanted but I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I did an easier way by using

```
body, html{
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

}

ty anyway!